# Getting random values from objects inside an array by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to a get a random string from the objects inside an array when you click the button. But for some reason my code is not executing.

```js
var quotes = [{
    quote: "Quote1",
    source: "Source1"
  },
  {
    quote: "Quote2",
    source: "Source2"
  },
  {
    quote: "Quote3",
    source: "Source3"
  },
  {
    quote: "Quote4",
    source: "Source4"
  },
  {
    quote: "Quote5",
    source: "Source5"
  }
];

function getRandomquote() {
  var randomindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
  var quotesarr = quotes[randomindex];
  var objquote = quotesarr.quote;
  var objsource = quotesarr.source;

  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = objquote;
  document.getElementById("source").innerHTML = objsource;
}

function printQuote() {
  document.getElementById("loadQuote").onclick = getRandomquote;
}
printQuote();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="quote-box">
    <p class="quote"> hello</p>
    <p class="source"> hello</p>
  </div>
  <button id="loadQuote" onclick="printQuote();">Show another quote</button>
```

I am getting this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
>       at HTMLButtonElement.getRandomquote (randomtest1.js:27)

**Update after answers below**

I changed `getElementById` to `getElementsByClassName`, and now there are no error messages.

But when I click the button, it does not change the elements. I believe I have made a mistake on the `printQuote` function. I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `getElementById` to retrieve an element by its `class`. You'll need to specify an `id` or use `getElementsByClassName`- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('test')
console.log(els.length)
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

In your example:

```
<p class="quote" id="quote"> hello</p>
<p class="source" id="source"> hello</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the ids to the elements as below. Or use `getElementsByClassName()` or use `querySelector(".quote")`.

```js
var objquote = "Hello";
var objsource = "World";
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=objquote;
document.getElementById("source").innerHTML=objsource;
```

```html
<div id="quote-box">
  <p id="quote" class="quote"> hello</p>
  <p id="source" class="source"> hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the working code below. i have removed unwanted functions.

html

```
<div id="quote-box">
  <p class="quote">hello</p>
  <p class="source">hello</p>
</div>
<button id="loadQuote" onclick="getRandomquote();">Show another quote</button>
```

js

```
var quotes=[
{quote:"Quote1", source:"Source1"},
{quote:"Quote2", source:"Source2"},
{quote:"Quote3", source:"Source3"},
{quote:"Quote4", source:"Source4"},
{quote:"Quote5", source:"Source5"}
        ];
getRandomquote=function(){

var randomindex=Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length));  
var quotesarr=quotes[randomindex];
document.getElementsByClassName("quote")[0].innerHTML=quotesarr.quote;
document.getElementsByClassName("source")[0].innerHTML=quotesarr.source;
}
```

Comment: when i click the button nothing happens with your code, but if i document.write just the quotesarr.quote and quotesarr,source seperately, it prints to the screen.

Comment: Its actually working. I have created a working pen and take a look in to it
http://codepen.io/jijocleetus/pen/ZeGvyv

Comment: Please check the above link and let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: Jijo, the problem is when i change the id attribute inside html and use getelementbyid in js, it works. but if i change it to class, it is not working.

Comment: For class attribute you need to use getElementsByClassName.

Comment: @alex472, I have identified the issue with getElementsByClassName property. If you use getElementsByClassName it will create an array of html elements. So if you use getElementsByClassName("quote") it will be an array with legth 0 since there is only one element with class="quote" so in norder to access it you need to provide the array element . In your case `document.getElementsByClassName("quote")[0].innerHTML=quotesarr.quote;`. 
updated pen is given below.
http://codepen.io/jijocleetus/pen/ZeGvyv

Comment: please let me know if you still have an issue with class

Comment: Jijo the problem is fixed. THX

Answer (score 0):

you have not set id in your p tag ...please set id='quote' and it should start working.

Answer (score 0):

I changed getElementById to getElementsByClassName, and now there are no error messages.

But when I click the button, it does not change the elements. I believe I have made a mistake on the printQuote function. I cannot figure it out.

Comment: All you do is re-assign the `onclick` event which doesn't do anything. Just call `getRandomquote()` instead of `document.getElementById("loadQuote").onclick = getRandomquote;`. Also it would be better to add this answer as a further edit to your question. :)

Comment: after the reassignment, the button is still not functioning.